# Variadic template function overloading

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates, overloading

I have a class with a variadic template member function (foo) like below. The idea is to skip all doubles in the parameter and allocate an object with user provided arguments.

```cpp
template <class T>
class Var {
public:

    template <typename U, typename ...Args>
    int foo(int index, Args... args)
    {
        T* p = new U(args...);
        // save in an array at index 'index'
    }

    template <typename U, typename ...Args>
    int foo (double index, Args... args)
    {
        // do something with index and skip it
        return foo<U>(args...);
    }
};

class A {
public:
    A (int i, const char *p)
    {

    }
};

int main ()
{
    Var<A> var;

    var.foo<A>(1.0, 2, 3, "Okay");
}
```

Now this works, there are 2 problem.

- Enforce how many doubles to skip.Eg: skip 2 doubles and then the next    argument should be an int. If it is not then throw error.
- While at it, use 'int' in place of 'double'. So we will skip 2 ints. The next index will be a 'index' to an array.

Basically I want to pass the no. of ints to skip as class template parameter.

```
template <class T, int SKIP>
class Var {
```

And use SKIP to determine how many ints to skip.

Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: I think it's possible to do something like that but imo the resulting code might be rather ugly and convoluted. Is this just an academic question or is there a practical problem you are trying to solve? It might help if you state a precise question, like, what exact behavior are you trying to get.

Comment: This is more academic. I have a solution which I added below based on the scheme suggested by Novelocrat. There was a actual use case in my code base, where we needed to store objects based on type OR type and sub-type. So lookup function is either (int type) or (int type, int subtype). But I didnt use this scheme there. Went for simpler solution of using 2 specialized classes where I redifined the same function (function name) with different set of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I conjured up taking hint from Novelocrat. Just pasting it hear for the records.

```
template <class T, int SKIP>
class FooHelper {
public:

    template <typename U, typename ...Args>
    static int foo_helper(int index, Args... args)
    {
        FooHelper<T, SKIP-1>::foo_helper<U>(args...);
        return 0;
    }
};

template <class T>
class FooHelper<T, 0> {
public:

    template <typename U, typename ...Args>
    static int foo_helper (Args... args)
    {
        auto p = new U(args...);
        return 0;
    }
};

template <class T, int SKIP>
class Var {
public:

    template <typename U, typename ...Args>
    int foo(Args ...args)
    {
        FooHelper<T, SKIP>::foo_helper<U>(args...);
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For your `SKIP` goal, you could do something like this:

```
template <typename U, typename ...Args>
int foo(Args ...args) {
  return foo_helper<U, 0>(std::forward(args));
}

template <typename U, int I, typename ...Args>
int foo_helper(int index, Args ...args) {
  return foo_helper<U, I+1>(std::forward(args));
}

template <typename U, typename ...Args>
int foo_helper<U, SKIP, Args...>(int index, Args ...args) {
  blah = new U(std::forward(args));
  return foobar;
}
```

Basically, have methods that count up to the target and strip off arguments until it's reached. Make a specialization for the target value.

Also, not that you'll probably want to `forward` the arguments to preserve references, etc.

I believe C++14 might make some of this easier, but I'm not familiar enough with newer template metaprogramming techniques to address that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But here aren't we doing partial specialization of function template? It not compiling. But the same technique with the template class specialization works.

Comment: You're right, it is partial specialization of a function template. I didn't think the above code through or test it directly. But yes, it can always be wrapped up in a class template to make it work.