# variadic template function overloading failes

Tags: c++, qt, templates, overloading, variadic

I am trying to implement some kind of `StringBuilder` for some unit tests. The problem is that I am heavily using `QByteArray` within some templates, which is using the `StringBuilder` for logging. In order to use `QByteArray` in an `QString().arg()` I usually have to wrap the byte array with `QString(...)`.

So I tried the following:

```
const char* buildCString(const QString& msg ){
    return msg.toLatin1().toStdString().data();
}

template<typename Head, typename ...Tail>
const char* buildCString(const QString& msg, const Head& arg, const Tail&... rest){
    return buildCString(msg.arg(arg), rest...); //generic use case 
}

template<typename Head, typename ...Tail>
 const char* buildCString(const QString& msg, const QByteArray& arg, const Tail&... rest){
    return buildCString(msg.arg(QString(arg)), rest...); 
}

void main(){
    auto data = buildCString("double %1, QByteArray %2, int %3", 0.123, QByteArray("Test"), 2);
    cout << "Data: " << data << endl;
}
```

And receive the following error:

```
In instantiation of 'const char* buildCString(QString, Head, Tail ...) [with Head = QByteArray; Tail = {int}]':
required from 'const char* buildCString(QString, Head, Tail ...) [with Head = double; Tail = {QByteArray, int}]'
required from here
Fehler: call of overloaded 'arg(QByteArray&)' is ambiguous
     return buildCString(msg.arg(arg), rest...);
```

So the generic function gets called instead of the more specialized one.

My question is why doesn't the overloading kick in? I have the feeling I am missing something basic here but after searching serveral hours for an solution I still can't wrap my head around it.

I am using Qt 5.9.0  and mingw32 5.3.0 32Bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this overload...

```
template<typename Head, typename ...Tail>
 const char* buildCString(const QString& msg, const QByteArray& arg, const Tail&... rest){
    return buildCString(msg.arg(QString(arg)), rest...); 
}
```

...the template parameter `Head` can never be deduced. You should get rid of it.

Comment: That was it, thanks! Btw, I've seen something like that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687615/variadic-template-function-overloading why is it valid there?

Comment: @RyanMcFlames Because he's providing the template argument at the call site (foo<U>(args...)). Your could have done it as well with buildCString<something>(...).